# File sharing lock count exceeded, runtime error 3052

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Okay so i have a macro that goes in and checks the table to determine the format of a application that is set by the user. If this format is set to be a European format then it runs a function that will go through a table and swap the date formatting from MM/dd/yyyy to dd/MM/yyyy. everything seems to be set up correctly and when it's in US formatting the macro runs correctly(which it should considering it skips over this line if the formatting is not set to European.) however, whenever the formatting is set to European, i get this run-time error that pops up:

```
    Run-Time error '3052':
File sharing lock count exceeded. Increase MaxLocksPerFile registry entry.
```

Now i'm always wary whenever i get an error that states the fix is to modify something in the registy. Not to mention this is not something i would want a client to be doing just to get the application to work. However i gave it a shot just to see if that would indeed fix the problem by following [these](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815281) steps. Although when i did modify the default MaxLocksPerFile from it's default(9500) to (30,000) and ran the macro again i still got the same error at a slightly larger count.

Before i would get the error after running through about 12,000 rows, after the change it would come up around 15,0000 rows.

This leads me to believe that i am incorrectly closing out my updates after each row is modified.

This is my code below:

```
    Public Function UKDateFormat() As Variant
Dim varPieces As Variant
Dim strNew As String
Dim varReturn As Variant
Dim Strsql As String
Dim db As dao.Database
Dim rstAlarmdetDateMod As dao.Recordset
Dim i As Long

Set db = CurrentDb()

Strsql = "select AlarmDate From AlarmdetDateMods;"
Set rstAlarmdetDateMod = db.OpenRecordset(Strsql, dbOpenDynaset)

If (rstAlarmdetDateMod.RecordCount > 0) Then
    rstAlarmdetDateMod.MoveFirst

i = 0


    While (rstAlarmdetDateMod.EOF) = False
    i = i + 1
       rstAlarmdetDateMod.Edit
       rstAlarmdetDateMod![alarmdate] = CDate(Format(rstAlarmdetDateMod![alarmdate], "dd/MM/yyyy"))
       rstAlarmdetDateMod.Update
       rstAlarmdetDateMod.MoveNext
    Wend
End If
rstAlarmdetDateMod.Close
db.Close


End Function
```

This is my Update query:

```
UPDATE DISTINCTROW AlarmdetDateMods SET AlarmdetDateMods.AlarmDate = CDate(Format([AlarmDate],"dd/mm/yyyy"));
```

What i would like to know is: What exactly i am doing wrong with my function that it causes this error to come up and how can i correct it in a way so that i don't have to go into and modify the registry to get this function to work?

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the data type of your AlarmDate field Date/Time or text?

Comment: It's a text, should i change it over to a Date/Time?

Comment: Depends on how you're using it I suppose.  A Date/Time value is actually a numeric data type ... the stored value is the same regardless of how you format it for display purposes.  My gut instinct is to use Date/Time type for Date/Time values as that makes it more convenient for date operations.  The values can be formatted for display purposes by setting the format property of a bound data control on a form, or using the Format() function in a query.  Your approach of changing every stored AlarmDate string in the table scares me!

Comment: How would you recommend going about it?

Comment: Without a JOIN in the FROM clause, DISTINCTROW serves no purpose whatsoever (as opposed to SELECT by itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to your UKDateFormat function, you showed us this UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE DISTINCTROW AlarmdetDateMods
SET AlarmdetDateMods.AlarmDate = CDate(Format([AlarmDate],"dd/mm/yyyy"));
```

However, it's not clear what's going on with that.  Does it work?  Does it fail with the same error as the UKDateFormat function?  A different error?

Try a revised UPDATE statement.  I think DISTINCTROW is not useful in this case; suggest you discard it.

Also your UPDATE seems to rely on implicit data type conversions.  AlarmDate is a text value.  You pass that text to the Format() function, to treat it as a Date/Time value and transform it to a different formatted string.  Then you ask CDate() convert that string value to a Date/Time value.  Finally the Date/Time value is stored back to the AlarmDate text field.

At a minimum I would avoid casting the formatted string back to a Date/Time value before storing it in the text field.  However, I would also make the data type conversions explicit rather than implicit.  And limit the UPDATE attempt to only those rows where AlarmDate holds the text representation of a valid Date/Time value.

```
UPDATE AlarmdetDateMods
SET AlarmDate = Format(CDate(AlarmDate),"dd/mm/yyyy")
WHERE IsDate(AlarmDate) = True;
```

Note this suggestion assumes changing all your stored AlarmDate text values is reasonable.  I have doubts about that.  Seems like maybe AlarmDate should be Date/Time rather than text.  And if you need to change the format when displaying those Date/Time values, do it with the format property of a bound control on a form or with the Format() function in a query.

Comment: Swapping AlarmDate from Text to Date/Time was exactly it, Thanks to that i don't even need the above code or updates anymore, since it appears that access will automatically format the text in the method i want it to be in now. Thanks!

Comment: Good!  I take it that means the users' locale settings automatically drive the appropriate Date/Time display format.  It's best when it can work that simply!